# execv example is segfaulting

Tags: assembly, x86

Hello I have a problem with the following execv example:

> jmp short       callit
>
> doit:
>
> pop             esi
>   xor             eax, eax
>   mov byte        [esi + 7], al
>   lea             ebx, [esi]
>   mov long        [esi + 8], ebx
>   mov long        [esi + 12], eax
>   mov byte        al, 0x0b
>   mov             ebx, esi
>   lea             ecx, [esi + 8]
>   lea             edx, [esi + 12]
>   int             0x80
>
> callit: 
>   call            doit
>   db             '/bin/sh#AAAABBBB'

Why is the code segfaulting?  I got it from: http://www.safemode.org/files/zillion/shellcode/doc/Writing_shellcode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to tell us how you are running this code and where it faults.

If you tried to put this into a stock executable then it presumably ended up in the read-only text section, hence the fault.

If you tried this from the stack, then that might not be executable, hence the fault.

Comment: I added global _start _start: and tried: nasm -f elf code.s -o code.o && ld code.o -o code && ./code ..

Comment: Yeah, the problem for you is the read-only `.text` section. Add `section rwtext exec write` at the top of the file.

Comment: wow works.. thx can you explain the section rwtext exec write?

Comment: Just creates a custom section named `rwtext` that's both executable and writable.